# How To Read A File and Look For a Specific Line to Another Line - Java

Tags: java, bufferedreader, readline, fileinputstream, writetofile

so I want to read a file and look for a specific line and the follow 50 lines or so, and remove those lines from that file and write the other lines to another file. I need some help getting started, and some ideas for an approach. I am planning on doing a simple way. For example, this will be the txt file:

```
hi
hey
12
14
456
234
23
bye
53
2312
434
```

I want to find the line hey and delete all lines from "hey" until "bye" (inclusive). and this will repeat in the file many times at various places (about 1000 times). Also, the number of lines in between will always be the same...so if possible I can even do delete from "hey" and the next ____ number of lines. Thanks for any ideas!

```
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("file name");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));

String strLine; 

//Read File Line By Line
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
  // Print the content on the console
  System.out.println (strLine);
}

//Close the input stream
br.close();
}
```

Comment: What OS are you using? If you're using Linux or OS X then you might be able to just use the `sed` command to do this.

Comment: Wait, so you just need to read the file line by line, and if you encounter the starting one then start ignoring the lines, then when you encounter the end one then ignore that and start NOT ignoring the lines? Do I understand it right? because that's fairly simple, just making sure I understand it right

Comment: I am not using Linux or OS X, but yeah so pretty much if I find the starting line, I have to look for the end of where it stops. But this pair of starting and ending lines will appear several times in the file, not just once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, it takes the two words as program arguments (for example `MyApp.jar hey bye`)

```
public class Main
{
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
         if(args.length < 2) 
         {
             System.exit(0);
         }
         String ignoreStartWord = args[0];
         String ignoreEndWord = args[1];
         BufferedReader br = null;
         BufferedWriter bw = null;
         try
         {
             br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File("fileName"))));
             bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File("fileName2"))));
             boolean ignoreStarted = false;
             String line = null;
             while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
             {
                 if(ignoreStarted == false)
                 {
                     if(line.equals(ignoreStartWord))
                     {
                         ignoreStarted = true;
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         bw.write(line);
                         bw.newLine();
                     }
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     if(line.equals(ignoreEndWord))
                     {
                         ignoreStarted = false;
                     }
                 }
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
             if(br != null) try { br.close(); } catch(IOException e) {}
             if(bw != null) try { bw.close(); } catch(IOException e) {}
        }
    }
}
```

INPUT:

```
hi
hey
12
14
456
234
23
bye
53
2312
434
hi
hey
12
14
456
234
23
bye
53
2312
434
hi
hey
12
14
456
234
23
bye
53
2312
434
hi
hey
12
14
456
234
23
bye
53
2312
434
```

OUTPUT:

```
hi
53
2312
434
hi
53
2312
434
hi
53
2312
434
hi
53
2312
434
```

Comment: This is the output I am expecting! Although how do you do the program arguments? Also, how if the line is starting with another word(s)? say like "1244<> error hey 235 fk5rft etc... AND if there is a space in the ignore word, it will not read it... thanks

Comment: errrr currently it just checks for the entire line if it matches the word you provided, and that word has no whitespace in the specification. Program arguments, if you run the code from Eclipse for example then there's an option for it to specify it, albeit in Eclipse what I tend to do is export the file as a Runnable JAR File then run it using 'java -jar exported.jar argument1 argument2' in command line

Comment: I'm pretty sure if the program arguments confuse you then you can just load them from a file, and if you want to remove spaces from the sides then you can just call trim().

Comment: thanks, I actually got it fixed. and I am able to run it successfully. Now I am just trying to get it to do more than 1 pair of keywords

Comment: that shouldn't be hard, once you figure out how to do it for **2**, then you can do it for **n**. The base algorithm is the same, the real magic is handling the multiple "ignore" states at the same time, aka you would need to store which word initiated the ignoration and then end it only if you meet its key pair close word.